# Remove item from array if value equals

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, orders, unset

On the Woocommerce order page, I have of items in the order, through which I want to loop and exclude a specific item **by product id**.

```
$order->get_order_number();
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach( $items as $key => $value) :
     $exclude = $value->get_product_id();
     if( in_array($exclude, array('3404') ) {  
        unset($items[$key]);
     }
  }
endforeach;

$new_items = array_values($items);
```

I thought this would loop through the original array, remove the `$item` whose `$product_id == 3404` and then reindex.

I'm having no luck here. Any thoughts?

**Solved ->**

```
        //Filter out colon cleanse duo
    $items = array_filter($order->get_items(), function($item) {
        return $item->get_product_id() != 3404;
    });

    //Randomize ids and grab one
    shuffle($items);
    foreach( $items as $item) :

        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_name = $item->get_name();

        break;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: If you only need one, you should leave the `foreach` with a `break;` after setting `$product_name`. Else you iterate over all items again and again, and get the last entry.

Comment: oh, so like this?

foreach( $items as $item) :

        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_name = $item->get_name();

       break;

    endforeach;

Comment: Exactly. That will save "some performance".

Comment: Great. I'm no developer so this is wonderful. I ought to look through all my other custom functions to see if I did the same. Thank you so much, Markus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
$items = array_filter($order->get_items(), function($item) {
    return $item->get_product_id() != 3404;
});
```

This iterates over `$items` and passes like a `foreach` each value to `$item`. If the callback of `array_filter` returns a `true`, the value will be kept else dropped.

You even can pass `$order->get_items()` directly in without fetching the items to an array.

Additionally if you require to exclude more than one, as asked in your comment, you can do like so:

```
$items = array_filter($order->get_items(), function($item) {
    return !in_array($item->get_product_id(), [3404, 6890]);
});
```

Comment: Hi Markus. Thanks for the response! I'm getting an error telling me that array_filter expects param 1 to be an array. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey Markus. I was hopin' you could help assist with this addition: if I wanted to exclude id 3404 AND id 6890, it looks like != array( 3404, 6890 ) doesn't work; and neither does != ( 6890 || 3404 ). Any suggestions?